# NPE: Spring boot - testing with mockmvc rest controller and when responsebody returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockmvc

Here is my Controller which I want to test using `mockmvc`:

```java
@Api(tags = "search")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:JavadocMethod")
public class SearchController {
    @Setter
    @Autowired
    private SearchService searchService;

    @ApiOperation("Search suggestions")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/suggest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CompletableFuture<ApiResponse<SuggestResponseData>> suggest(
            @RequestBody @Validated ApiRequest<SuggestRequest> request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                throw new RequestValidationException(bindingResult);
        }
        return searchService.suggest(request.getRequestBody());
    }
}
```

so here is my **tests**:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SearchControllerTest.SearchControllerTestConfiguration.class)
public class SearchControllerTest {
    private static final String TEST_STRING = "test";
    @Autowired
    private SearchService searchService;
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        final SearchController searchController = new SearchController();
        searchController.setSearchService(searchService);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(searchController).build();    
    }


    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void givenOKResponse_whenValidRequest() throws Exception {
        final ApiRequestHeader header = getApiRequestHeader();
        final ApiRequest<SuggestRequest> apiRequest = getApiRequest(header, TEST_STRING, Collections.singletonList(TEST_STRING));
        given(searchService.suggest(apiRequest.getRequestBody())).willReturn(buildSuggestResponse());

        mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/suggest")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(apiRequest))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print());
    }

    private ApiRequest<SuggestRequest> getApiRequest(ApiRequestHeader header, String query, List list) {
        return new ApiRequest(header, new SuggestRequest(query, list));
    }
```

when `.andDo(print());`, I expect that some json will be printed in body but i got empty:

```
Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

this is my **configuration**:

```java
@Configuration
public static class SearchControllerTestConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Bean
    public MockMvc mockMvc() {
        return MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SearchService searchService() {
        return Mockito.mock(SearchService.class);
    }
}
```

I thought that test not working because I've used `ComplitableFuture` in response but I'm not running `async` methods I just wrap my response in Completable future. Here **I try to do** something like this:

```java
return searchService.suggest(request.getRequestBody())
    .thenApply(response -> {
        System.out.println(response.getResponseBody()); //here is NPE but why????
        return response;
    });
}
```

Why do I get an NPE while logging the response above?

Comment: what does this return `apiRequest.getRequestBody()`?

Comment: @Deadpool ```apiRequest.getRequestBody()``` will return ```SuggestRequest.class``` and it is a simple class with two ```String```  variables

Comment: I believe that problem is while comparing the input arguments, can you try this `ArgumentMatchers.eq(new ApiRequest<SuggestRequest>(){})` or first try this `ArgumentMatchers.any()`